# Only one program showing in the top panel

Tags: gnome

I just started using Gnome today and I'm having a stupid difficulty to understand why, when I have more then one program open I can't see it on my top bar.

To change between applications, I have to tab all time and I really don't like it.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnome-Shell is a very different work-flow compared to the traditional desktops like the previous Gnome-2 interface.

You can see all your running apps by clicking the Activities menu option.

Fortunately, there is the ability to "extend" the interface through [extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/)

For example you can install "frippery bottom panel" to have a more traditional panel to choose your running applications

[image]

or you could have a "Dock" which appears and disappears on the right-hand side of the screen depending if you position your mouse in that area.

[image]

If you dont want to use extensions you could use tint2:

[image]

```
sudo apt-get install tint2
```

add `tint2` to your startup applications

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any insight into why the gnome-shell devs designed window management the way they did, but I do have two functional solutions for you, the first of which my may have already noticed.

The most efficient way to navigate vanilla gnome-shell is simply through the overview, which depending on your configuration can be achieved by mousing over the hot-zone in the upper left corner (or wherever you may have manually placed it), clicking the activities icon in the upper left corner, or pressing super.

If you're looking for a more legacy gnome environment, I would recommend installing the [Bottom Panel Extension](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/bottom-panel-gnome2-like-panel-gnome.html)

Hope this helps.